# Последовательный выбор select (jQuery/JavaScript)

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, php, javascript

Как сделать, чтобы содержимое второго `<select>` зависело от выбора элемента первого `<select>`. Т.е. пока пользователь не выбрал пункт в первом (а именно в нем стоит на `<option>---</option>`), то во втором есть атрибут disabled. Когда уже выбрал, то атрибут убирается и создается меню с пунктами, зависимыми от выбора пункта в первом меню.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать такую штуковину, или может есть готовые плагины?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используя jquery:
http://jsfiddle.net/866LM/

Answer (score 0):

Ну есть 2 решения:
1-й:

```
<script>
var dipla = 0;
function GetSel(i){
document.getElementById('pse-'+dipla).style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('pse-'+i).style.display = 'block';
dipla = i;
}
</script>
 <select id=main OnChange="GetSel(this.selectedIndex);"><option selected value="1 случай">1 случай</option><option value="2 случай">2 случай</option></select>
<select id=pse-0>...</select> <!--Первый случай -->
<select id=pse-1 style="display:none;">...</select><!--Второй случай -->
```

И второй, более профессиональный и оптимизированный через AJAX, но в нём нет смысла если в первом селекте не много случаев. А вот если идёт речь об странах и городах - то желательно этот способ. Я его расписывать не буду, т.к. это очень много.

Answer (score 0):

Типа:

```
<script>$('первый_селект').change(function(el){$('второй_селект').removeAttr('disabled').append('пункты, генерируемые каким-нибудь скриптом, в зависимости от значения el')});</script>
```

Только это уже, кажется, плохой тон - принято сразу показывать первый пункт в первом селекте и разлоченный второй с зависимыми пунктами. Тоесть, накаких "выберите страну" внутри селектов